# Spring data jpa create or update

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

In the webserver I'm developing we receive requests from our users' clients and then the webserver requests some resource from another server and returns that resource to the client. After returning the result from the other web server we want to sync our database with the records returned from the other web server. I was wondering if there is any way to do this without using a select then update.

For example we get `Resource {id=null, uniqueField=valWontChange, field1=val, field2=val2}` from the other webserver while in our db we have `Resource {id=1, uniqueField=valWontChange, field1=oldVal, field2=val2}`. I would rather not do something like

```java
Resource resDb = repo.getByUniqueField(res.uniqueField);
if (resDb != null) {
    res.id = resDb.id;
}
repo.save(res);
```

I could use something like:

```java
@Modifying
@Query("update Resource r set field1 = ?1, field2= ?2 where r.uniqueField=?3")
boolean updateWhereUniqueField(Object field1, Object field2, Object uniqueField);

void createOrUpdate(Resource res) {
    boolean updated = updateWhereUniqueField(res.field1, res.field2, res.uniqueField);
    if (!updated) {
        save(res);
    }
}
```

This I think would be undesirable if there are lots of fields for a resource, I would have to pass all fields seperately to the method. Is there a better way to go about this? If not, does anybody have experience with the methods described above and do they know which option would be better in the case where an entity can have quite a lot of fields?

Comment: why don't you use native queries? create native queries dynamically according to the fields which needs to be updated.

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative is to use a [merge statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/merge-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) in the `@Query` that many databases support by now. It has the benefit of getting handled in a single roundtrip.

For both the JPA update and the SQL merge you may employ [SpEL expressions](https://spring.io/blog/2014/07/15/spel-support-in-spring-data-jpa-query-definitions) so you can use the entity as a single argument.

Comment: +1 Although it seems like mysql (which I'm using) doesn't support merge statements. I suppose I could use `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` but that has it's own limitations. Thanks for your info, I'll be looking a but further in to this.